# Is there a friendlier way of viewing data structures when in edebug?

Tags: edebug

When stepping through a function in edebug I often strain to decipher the data structures that get printed on one line in the minibuffer.  Here's one example:
[image]
Often I'm looking at structures two or three times this long. Is there a package or customization that can display these structures in another window with friendly lisp formatting?  It would also be great if I could easily search the data structure for a string of interest.

Many thanks for suggestions.  I'm new to emacs lisp and probably spoiled by working with IntelliJ IDEs.  But I really want to improve my lisp chops.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Thanks for removing the tag. Sorry about that!

Comment: (The term you need to search for is "pretty print".) I didn't have time to test myself, so not writing as an answer, but try to use [`pp` build-in package](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EvaluatingExpressions). See also https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/jqsdcr/how_do_you_debug_giant_plists/ and https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/7htdzk/show_reddit_prettyprint_debugger_frames/ Ping me if you make it work ;-)